# how to pass data from my controller to the view in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

am trying to retrieve data from the controller and send it through and email to student but it not working .i have tried it but it not going

```
public function test(){
        
       
        $welcome = DB::table('results')
        ->select('studentinfos_id','marks','subject_code','name','email','rollid','classname','classnumber','image_path')
        ->join('studentinfos','studentinfos.id','=','results.studentinfos_id')
        ->join('subjects','subjects.id','=','results.subjects_id')
        ->join('addclasses','addclasses.id','=','results.addclasses_id')
      

        ->where('studentinfos.id',1)
        ->orderBy('subject_code','ASC')
        ->get();

        
            
        Mail::to('serge@gmaile','divine')->cc('leade@gmail')->send(new mytestmail($welcome));
            
           
    echo 'check ur inbox';

       
   }
```

how do i get all the result from the $welcome in my view.blade.php

i was hopping that i will send and email that contains student info and result of there marks and subject through email

```
 
<div class="container">
 
 

<div class="text-center">


  <h1> Result for {{ $classname }} student </h1>

</div>



<div class="border bg-white seespace p-3">






<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">


  <table class="table  table-borderless">
        <tr>
        <th>CLASS</th>
        <td>{{ $welcome->classname  }} {{ $welcome->classnumber }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>FULL NAME</th>
        <td>: {{ $welcome->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <td>: {{ $welcome->email }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ENROLLMENT</th>
        <td>: {{ $welcome->enrollment }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <img class=" imgreport center" src="{{ asset('images/' .  $welcome->image)  }}" 
       
       alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
</div>






<nav class="bg-dark text-white-50 mb-5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row p-3">
     
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>









 <table class="table text-center table-bordered table-responsive py-3">
    <thead class="thead-info text-center">
        <tr>
            <th>no</th>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>marks</th>
            
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $num=1;
        $total = 0;
        $name;
        ?>
        @foreach($welcome as $see)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $num++ }}</td>
            <td>{{ $see->subject_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $see->marks }}</td>
            
           
            
                
            
        
        </tr>
<?php    

$total += $see->marks  ?>
        @endforeach
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td >total marks</td>
          <td>{{ $total }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Download</td>
          
            
          <td>
                <form action="/print" method="get">
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$studnet}}" name='id' >
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Download</button>
                </form>
            

            </td>
                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>



</div>
</div>

@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the welcome variable to your view.
In the controller method add the data when displaying your view:

```
return view('view', ['welcome' => $welcome]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views